# How can I set an instance variable as a fileHandle in python?

Tags: python, file, instance-variables, filehandle

I want to define a class which attaches a fileHandle to a class. For example, I can define a class with an instance variable as a file handler object, but it is not safe when the object is eventually dereferenced.

```
class CustomLoggingClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fileHandle = open("logFile.json", "w+")
```

How could I implement this in a safe way so that logFile.json will be closed properly?

Comment: When do you need this file to be closed?

Comment: when this object is destructed. For example, I want to add an instance of this class as an attribute to any class which requires logging. The reason for not using an already existing logging library is that I want to implement it into a json format for the administrator console.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest thing to do would be to create a helper context manager function with the`contextlib.contextmanager`decorator and then use it in conjunction with a`with` statement. For example:

```
class CustomLoggingClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fileHandle = open("logFile.json", "w+")

    def close(self):
        self.fileHandle.close()

import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm_logger():
    logger = CustomLoggingClass()
    yield logger
    logger.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with cm_logger as logger:
        # do stuff with logger, a CustomLoggingClass instance
        pass
```

The `with` statement and context managers are discussed in [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).